# Javascript passing value to open window

Tags: javascript

How do i go about passing the value of width ,height,resize received as parameter to window.open using javascript?

Thanks

Example

```
function poponload(mywidth,myheight,resizeVal)
{
   testwindow = window.open ("http://www.yahoo.com", "mywindow","location=1,status=1,scrollbars=1,width=+mywidth+,height=myheight,resizeVal");
   testwindow.moveTo(0,0);
}

<body onload="javascript: poponload(200, 500,yes)">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
testwindow= window.open ("http://www.yahoo.com", "mywindow","location=1,status=1,scrollbars=1,width="+mywidth+",height="+myheight+",resizeVal");
```

use this see the string concatenation

Answer (score 5):

```
function poponload(mywidth,myheight,resizeVal) {
    testwindow= window.open("http://www.yahoo.com", "mywindow", "location=1,status=1,scrollbars=1,width="+mywidth+",height="+myheight+",resizable="+resizeVal);
    testwindow.moveTo(0,0);
}
```

Also you should then pass in "1" or "0" for resizeVal, like so:

```
<body onload="poponload(200,500,1)">
```

Further reading:

- [Concatenating Strings (+)](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/strings.html#conc)
- [Concatenating strings with the + operator](http://www.scriptingmaster.com/javascript/concatenating-strings-javascript.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Also, `body onload="javascript: poponload(200, 500,yes)"` is one `javascript:` too many.